# How to call the class having key pair as a arguments

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
class QRCodeGenerator extends SampleView {
  /// Creates the QR barcode generator sample
  const QRCodeGenerator(Key key) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _QRCodeGeneratorState createState() => _QRCodeGeneratorState();
}
```

how to call this function in the main.dart as it required something to be written in the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can call in Flutter:

```
QRCodeGenerator(GlobalKey());
```

If you want to make the key argument optional, you can do something like that:

```
class QRCodeGenerator extends SampleView {
  /// Creates the QR barcode generator sample
  const QRCodeGenerator({Key key}) : super(key: key); // add curley braces
  @override
  _QRCodeGeneratorState createState() => _QRCodeGeneratorState();
}
```